# While loop with two input invocations

Tags: python, while-loop

I am learning Python and I am having trouble with while loops. I have a sample code below and it includes a while loop. What I am want to do here is print “Ha! You’ll never guess” every time the correct name is not predicted, but I also want the code to print “No! how did you guess?” when the right name is predicted. I have been playing around with it, and it does do what I want but the system I have to test my code it says it is incorrect and that my program tried to read more inputs than it should have needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
print("You will never win the game, for Scooby dooby doo! is my name.")
rumple = input("Guess my name: ")

while rumple != "Rumplestiltskin":

        print("Ha! You'll never guess!")
        rumple = input("Guess my name: ")



print('No! How did you guess?')
```

Comment: This looks fine, though you have a bit of repeated code (the call to `input()`) which you could remove. But the real problem you're describing, "the system I have to test my code" - is what we would need to see to determine what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the task is to only have a single `input` function, you could change your while loop to

```
while "Rumplestiltskin" != input("Guess my name: "):
    print("Ha! You'll never guess!")

print('No! How did you guess?')
```

This places your `input` function into the while loop without requiring the rumple variable to be initialised beforehand.

Comment: This appears to behave identically to the code in the question. How does this solve the problem of the OP's test system saying "tried to read more inputs than it should"?

Answer (score 0):

Which System do you use? I tested your code, after I corrected the indentation and I get no errors or warnings.

```
print("You will never win the game, for Scooby dooby doo! is my name.")
rumple = input("Guess my name: ")

while rumple != "Rumplestiltskin":
    print("Ha! You'll never guess!")
    rumple = input("Guess my name: ")

print('No! How did you guess?')
```

My results:

```
You will never win the game, for Scooby dooby doo! is my name.
Guess my name: Scooby
Ha! You'll never guess!
Guess my name: Rumplestiltskin
No! How did you guess?

Process finished with exit code 0
```